# Создать формулу рассадки игроков за столами

Tags: алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

У нас есть n столов, за которыми помещаются n игроков одновременно.
Необходимо создать формулу рассадки n*n игроков за n столами на максимальное количество раундов так, в конечном итоге каждый игрок сыграет с другим игроком не больше одного раза.

Я пробовал расписывать на бумажке, получалось примерно следующее.
Для n=3

```
123 456 789
159 483 726
168 429 735
147 258 369
```

Так же сформировал для n=4

```
1234 vbcd абвг 6789
17вd v28г аb39 6бc4
1б8b v4в9 а2с7 63гd
1v6a 2бd9 3cв8 4bг7
1сг9 2bв6 3vб7 4da8
```

Но я не могу вывести общую формулу, мне необходима такая рассадка для 10 игроков для 10 столов. Интуитивно кажется, что, согласно условиям, рассадку можно сформировать для 11 игр, но я не знаю, как правильно подходить к решению этой задачи.

Мои мысли и попытки решения:
1)Думал о том, что мы каждого игркоа на новый раунд сдвигаем на какое-то количество мест. И нам необходимо, чтобы ни одна пара игроков не играла дважды, поэтому можно создать что-то вроде маски сдвигов по примеру[0, 1, 2 ,3], которую применять к игрокам каждого стола, и формировать эту маску на каждый раунд так, чтобы суммарный сдвиг(маршрут) игроков, которые выходят из одной точки, не равнялся, потому что они тогда "сойдутся" за одним столом. Но этого недостаточно, в рассадке на троих возможна комбинация 147 258 369, сформированная путём группировки игроков по "разрядам", а не сдвигом. Получается, игрок перемещается не только по столам, но и по "разрядам", то есть маску надо формировать двумерную, и в этот момент это стало слишком сложно для меня, к тому же вполне вероятно, что это тупиковый вариант.

2) Пробовал написать программу, которая формирует такие столы тупым перебором, но у меня проблема с алгоритмом.
Я писал так: каждый раунд мы выбираем из оставшегося пула игроков того, кто ещё не "знаком" ни с кем из игроков, уже набранных для данного стола, когда укомплектовали - идём к следующему. Столкнулся с тем, что уже на 3 раунде для случая n=3 можно начать укомплектовывать первые два стола так, что на третьем столе "пасьянс" уже не сойдётся, так как все оставшиеся игроки будут друг с другом знакомы. А на этапе формирования первого стола у нас недостаточно информации для того чтобы заглянуть в "остаток" для третьего стола. Возможно нужно формировать что-то вроде дерева решений, формировать список игроков подходящих для первого стола, и "смотреть", что будет если взять каждого конкретного игрока из списка, но это становится уже сложнее, и я тут решил попросить помощи у вас.

Вполне возможно, эта задача решается по щелчку пальцев, я просто туповат.

Comment: поясните, вам нужен алгоритм посадки, например за 3 стола, по 4 посадочных места на каждом, 12 игроков, так что б ни один игрок не играл с кем либо за столом дважды?

Answer (score 1):

Решение действительно простое. 1 игрок может сыграть со всеми остальными по одному разу. При этом за один раз, он может сыграть с n-1 игроками. Всего игроков, с которыми нужно сыграть, n^2-1. Разделим их на группы по n-1 игроков. (N^2-1)/(n-1) = ((n-1)*(n+1))/(n-1) = n+1.

Алгоритм рассадки:

1. Разбиваем ваших участников на n групп. Неважно как. Это первый раунд.
2. Нумеруем участников двумя индексами [группа, номер в группе]
3. на i-ом шаге собираем группу по следующему правилу: на место в [группа, номер] берем участника [(группа + номер)MOD n, номер] из рассадки предыдущего шага. На n+1 шаге алгоритм зациклится, поэтому его придется обрабатывать отдельно.
4. Последний шаг формируем так: на место в [группа, номер] берем участника [номер, группа] из рассадки предыдущего шага.

Comment: Не вижу подсказки в том, как создать формулу рассадки

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, но не понимаю один момент. Смотрите, мы сдвинули всю группу кроме "зафиксированного" игрока за другой стол. Ну тогда каждый в этой подгруппе сыграет с каждым из подгрупы второй раз, разве нет? уникальных партнёров во втором раунде получат только "зафиксированный" игрок из каждой группы.

Comment: @MayRiv Вот так все партнеры всегда уникальны

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать